# Perforce - Specify target directory path for sync

Tags: perforce, p4v

Is it possible to specify the folder name where depot needs to be synced ?

I tried syncing the depot to my specified path using following command but it does not work.

> p4sync -d "c:\my\path" sync //depot//branch/file

**Note :** My aim is just to copy the file from depot to my specified location.

Looks like **sync** is not the command I should be using. Is there any other command or way I can do this ?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just want to use the normal sync mechanism, with the workspace set up to put the files where you want?

Answer (score 2):

sync - gets files from depot to your workspace, which must be already customized. To get files without workspace you need to make some hack with command "print":

```
p4 print -o filename //path/on/depot/filename
```

This command (above) gets filename and store it in "filename". Also, you can make some another workaround to get all files from some directory, probably with "p4 -x - command" ( -x stands for xargs in unix-world)